# UI design for mobile and tablet both

Tags: android, android-layout

As I am designing UI for mobiles and tablet both. And also I have designed UI for mobiles and tablets, which will support all size of mobiles screens and tablets  (Nexus 7'' inch and 10' inch and for Samsung too) but when I am using same screen  (or you tell apk) to iball tablet (600*1024 resolution) or some micromax tablets then it start taking the mobile screen size of 3.7 inch  (hdpi). My UI becomes bad on that tablets. Is there is any solution to make UI to use on all of the tablets?

Comment: Have a look at the video.
 http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/59642335041/trying-slidingpanelayout-with-fragments-in-android

Comment: Screen size is completely different from resolution. U can have a xxxhdpi Nexus 5 device which has 5" screen and a tablet 10" with mdpi(low resolution). I think u are confusing both together

Comment: True, as a beginner it took me couple of weeks understanding difference between size and resolution!

Comment: @ Naresh I know that screen size is different from resolution but when mobile r giving resolution (like 600*1024) so we had made UI for that resolution and also in UI designing WE will made UI by resolutions only not by screen size.nd when we create emulator it will show screen size only.... i AM having 600*1024 resolution 7 inch tablet so Wat folder i have to user to support it

Comment: @ Astral Sir I m not beginner. i have made UI's before but its for Nexus and samsung nd it properly working but now with some other tablets its creating problem

Answer (score 3):

you can use layout-sw600dp and layout-sw720dp  layout folder to design the UI of tablets

Comment: Sir I had used it but still it taking the layout of hdpi only

Comment: are you using image in drawable in layout

Comment: yes sir I have made the same name drawable folder but still it taking the layout of HDPi

Comment: make  drawable-sw600dp and drawable-sw720dp

Comment: i made it Sir . the same folder

Comment: but its still not working please change the image size according to 600px and 720px

Comment: i have made the image of proper size but still its not supported and its a problem of layout sir not of image size ...tablet is not taking the layout of layout-sw600dp ???

Comment: actually i have used this method and it is working properly in my app.

Comment: Sir i Also used before in my app nd its working for nexus and Samsung tablets but with iball ,micromax its not working fine

Answer (score 3):

You need draw different layout in different size device
Create layout folder in res

1. layout-xlarge
2. layout-large
3. layout-normal
4. layout-small

and create same xml in different size layout folder so that you can custom layout in different size device

Comment: Dear i have made Layout folders in res                              1-layout-ldpi                                                       2-layout-mdpi                                                       3-layout-hdpi                                                       4-layout-xhdpi                                                      5-layout-xxhdpi                                                    6- layout-sw600dp - for tablet 7inch                              7- layout-sw720dp - for tablet 8inch                               8- layout-sw800dp - for tablet 10inch

Answer (score 1):

**Finally I have done it . I had use weight to do this and only I have made a Single Ui which will support in all mobile devices and tablets of any sizes ...
If any one need help plz contact me**

Comment: ...I am also facing the same problem..Can you please help me?